# Global Search in Salesforce External Connector ( Odata V4.01 ) not working

Tags: externalobjects, odata, salesforce-connect

With Odata v4.01 developed using Apache Olingo , I am facing issues with global search. While searching for an Id in global search, Salesforce is not triggering any request back to odata service. I didn't receive any api call with $filter criteria.

[image: External object info on Validate and Sync]

by default search is disabled on external objects level.
[image: external data sources]
though search is enabled on external data source.
[image: Case_x Object records are visible]
Search is enabled on Case object but on global searching same id we get :

[image: global search]

[image: global search result]

What i am missing ?

Comment: Open a support case.

Answer (score 0):

when External Object's search is disabled, you won't get any results from that entity, no matter what the External Datasource says. Also, I'm not sure if global search by ID is a valid use case. SOSL only searches certain field types.